# How to close an AdSense account

Tags: google-adsense

I created an AdMob account (great irreversible error). A week later, I was trying to create an AdSense account, but it was automatically created when I create the AdMob account. The AdSense account is unoperative. Fine, is logical.

But now, I can't ask for a functional AdSense account, due to a famous bug between AdMob / AdSense. All recommendations tell me to delete all accounts and begin from scratch from another Google account.

The Google instructions tell me that I need to cancel AdMob, AdWord and AdSense accounts. I closed the AdWord account, but AdMob tells me that I have to close the AdSense account first. But I can't!!! There is no such link. All pages give me a page with instructions, but always says

> In the “Account information” section, click cancel account.

This link doesn't exist! How on earth I can delete forever that AdSense account that I did not create?

I cannot associate a new AdSense account with another Google account because the old one exists and a lot of details are similar (I refuse to use the account of a familiar).

Comment: I have the exact same issue, not resolved yet and I fear that it is being widely ignored by Google. You can cancel your admob account from the admob interface under Account settings but this has not changed anything, still have the empty useless adsense account. I even applied for a new adsense account with another google login but they denied this with the reason that I was already a registered adsense user on another account. No possibility for replying on any of this or contacting Google.

Comment: I am in the same situation yet. Google ignores me. I have sent two support forms, only one have been answered, tell me the same thing, that i must use a delete account link in AdSense, a link that do not exist. I have no options, so frustrating...

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to get rid of the old AdSense account created by AdMob.

- Create a new "dummy" Google account
- Go to Account Settings in AdSense on your real account
- Click Users & Authentication
- Click add new user and type in the email of the dummy Google account
- Mark the new user row as being an administrator
- Log in to the dummy mail account and accept the AdSense invitation
- Log in to AdSense with the dummy account
- Remove your own real account using the X cross

That is it, you are no longer locked down by the AdMob/AdSense crisis and can now apply for a new AdSense for content account.

Use an incognito browser session for the fake account and you are done in less than a minute.

Comment: I do what you say. But when i am going to register in adsense with a new account, it tells me that am already associated to an account. Now it says the offending account is the fake one, instead of the old one. I am still unable to delete de adsense account or to create a new one.